# Mistakes after inserting Geogebra code

Tags: compiling

My tex file did not have any mistakes during compilation but when I inserted a code from Geogebra I see one mistake after compilation and I don't know how to fix it.
Can anyone help me please?

[image]

[image]

P.S.

```
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.41 \usepackage
                {chngcntr}
The package color has already been loaded with options:
  []
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
  [usenames,dvipsnames]
Adding the global options:
  ,usenames,dvipsnames
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/chngcntr/chngcntr.sty
Package: chngcntr 2018/04/09 v1.1a change counter resetting
Package chngcntr Info: \counterwithout already defined.
(chngcntr)             Quitting chngcntr on input line 21.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2021-06-07 v7.00m Hypertext links for LaTeX
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.styPackage: kvdefinekeys 2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty
Package: pdfescape 2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty
Package: hycolor 2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty
Package: letltxmacro 2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2020-10-07 v3.14 Key value format for package options (HO)
)
\@linkdim=\dimen301
\Hy@linkcounter=\count317
\Hy@pagecounter=\count318
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def
File: pd1enc.def 2021-06-07 v7.00m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PD1 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PD1
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref-langpatches.def
File: hyperref-langpatches.def 2021-06-07 v7.00m Hyperref: patches for babel languages
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty
Package: intcalc 2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count319
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def
File: puenc.def 2021-06-07 v7.00m Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PU ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PU
)
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4192.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4197.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4200.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4207.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4212.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4445.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count320
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip17
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 4804.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen302
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
Package: bitset 2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty
Package: bigintcalc 2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
))
\Fld@menulength=\count321
\Field@Width=\dimen303
\Fld@charsize=\dimen304
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6076.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6081.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6084.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6091.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6096.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6101.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6106.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6146.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6150.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty
Package: atbegshi-ltx 2021/01/10 v1.0c Emulation of the original atbegshi
package with kernel methods
)
\Hy@abspage=\count322
\c@Item=\count323
\c@Hfootnote=\count324
)
Package hyperref Info: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
File: hpdftex.def 2021-06-07 v7.00m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty
Package: atveryend-ltx 2020/08/19 v1.0a Emulation of the original atvery package
with kernel methods
)
\Fld@listcount=\count325
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count326
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.styPackage: rerunfilecheck 2019/12/05 v1.9 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.styPackage: uniquecounter 2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 286.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip66
)
Package hyperref Info: Option `linktocpage' set `true' on input line 97.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2021-07-12 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count327
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box66
) (./output.aux)
\openout1 = `output.aux'.
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots but text, and provide a full example. Right now it's not clear how GeoGebra is related to the issue (and to TeX at all). The error suggestes that you are loading the package `color` twice.

Comment: @campa, what do i need to upload?

Comment: @campa, please take a look at the edit. Is it possible to fix my mistake?

Comment: It's impossible without seeing the whole code, which as I already told shouldn't be posted as picture. Please provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917).

Comment: On line 39 you are loading the package `color`, but it's like you already load it (or use a package that did it) prior line 24. You have to remove all declaration you made and which are made again by GeoGebra's imported lines (`color` but also `graphicx` and `subfig` if you did)